# How can I change an element in a list of lists

Tags: python, list, numpy, tuples, structure

I have the following structure:

```
list_of_tuples = [['portugal', np.nan, 'japan'], [np.nan, 'germany', 'canada'], ['UK', 'US', np.nan]]
```

I want to change the numpy nan values for **MissingValue** and turning back to a list of tuples:

```
final_structure = [('portugal', 'MissingValue', 'japan'), ('MissingValue', 'germany', 'canada'), ('UK', 'US', 'MissingValue')]
```

How can I replace the elements given a condition without iterating all over the elements? is there any single statement?

Comment: numpy NaN sorry. @Jerrybibo

Comment: Can you post expected output?

Comment: done, you can check it now @Rakesh

Comment: You can't; you have to examine each of the elements to determine which ones need changing.  It's possible to write a one-liner, but it tsill must examine each value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to do it without iterating because tuples are immutable. However, you can use list comprehension to create a new list of tuples within a single line, following

```
final_structure = [ tuple([ j if isinstance(j, str) else "MissingValue" for j in l ]) for l in list_of_tuples ]
```

In your specific case, you can replace everything that is not a string (the `np.nan`) by `"MissingValue"` using the intrinsic function `isinstance()`.

Answer (score 1):

This is one approach.

```
import numpy as np

list_of_tuples = [['portugal', np.nan, 'japan'], [np.nan, 'germany', 'canada'], ['UK', 'US', np.nan]]
list_of_tuples = map(lambda x: tuple(["MissingValue" if i is np.nan else i for i in x]), list_of_tuples)
print(list_of_tuples)
```

**Output:**

```
[('portugal', 'MissingValue', 'japan'), ('MissingValue', 'germany', 'canada'), ('UK', 'US', 'MissingValue')]
```